# How can I make html columns expandable with touch events on a tablet (Android)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, touch-event

I'm trying to make the columns of a page that consists of 6 columns to be expandable on tablet (Android). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think flexbox container should be enough to fulfill your needs.

#html

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
</div>
```

#css

```
.row {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: red;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.column {
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: bisque;
}
```

Comment: Sorry if my explanation is vague. I need a page to have a touch function (for a Android tablet). The user would be able to widen and shorten columns similar to what you can do with Excel spreadsheets. Only with touch events.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about Collapse? The you can use Bootstrap Accordion
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/accordion/